# How to use keyframes

Tags: javafx

I'm unclear how how to use keyframes with an indefinite timeline. Here's my relevant code:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

//Stuff that will execute between frames
traverse();
printGrid(display);
```

The last two lines calculate the next frame and update the display. There's no transitions, just frame after frame. What do I wrap around the last two lines to do that?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAFADFJ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html